# prove by induction: $\forall n \in N, \exists k \in N: 165^{2n} - 1 = 166k$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I am trying to prove by induction: $\forall n \in N, \exists k \in N: 165^{2n} - 1 = 166k$.

But I've never come across having to possibly induct on two variables?

The base case for $n=1$ is true for $k = 164$

With the inductive hypothesis: assume $165^{k} - 1 = 166k$ we will prove that $165^{2k+2} - 1 = 166k$.

Where can I start on the inductive step?

Comment: you're inducting on one variable $n$, not two

Comment: is that the right approach?

Comment: The given statement basically says $166$ divides $165^{2n}-1$. so there is only one variable to induct on here...

Comment: You need to prove $165^{2n}\equiv1\mod166$ for all natural numbers. Note that $165\equiv-1\mod166$ which is enough to prove the statement without induction, since $165^{2n}\equiv(-1)^{2n}=1\mod166$

Comment: $165^{2n+2}-1=165^2165^{2n}-1=(165^2-1+1)165^{2n}-1 = (165^2-1)165^{2n}+(165^{2n}-1)$ and conclude

Comment: It would be less confusing if you used a different variable during inductive hypothesis.

Comment: In the inductive hypothesis step assume $$165^{2t} - 1 = 166k$$ for some $k$
and show that $165^{2(t+1) }-1=166k$ for some other $k$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n=m\in\Bbb N$ let $165^{2m}-1 = 166 k  \implies \color{blue}{165^{2m} = 166k+1}\ , k \in \Bbb N$
For $n=m+1$,

$$165^{2m+2} - 1 = \color{blue}{165^{2m}}\cdot165^2-1 = (\color{blue}{166k+1})165^2 - 1$$
$$165^{2m+2} - 1 = 166\cdot165^2k+165^2-1 = 166\cdot165^2k+166\cdot164 = 166k'$$

$k' = 165^2k+164\in \Bbb N$

Comment: do you mind explaining where you got $k'$ from

Comment: As $165, k , 164 \in \Bbb N \ , k ' = 165^2k + 164 \in \Bbb N $. i.e, it's another natural number. Our motto is to show that $165^{2m+2} -1 $ is divisible by $166$. So it doesn't matter what natural number you have in product with $166$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : For induction, the base case is fine, and suppose that $165^{2n}- 1 = 166 k_n$ for some integer $k_n$ depending on $n$.

Then note that $$(165^{2(n+1)}-1) - (165^{2n}-1) = 165^{2(n+2)} - 165^{2n} = 165^{2n}(165^2-1) = 165^{2n} \times 166 \times 164$$

And find $k_{n+1}$ in terms of $k_n$ now.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(m)=165^{2m}-1,$

$f(n+1)-165^2f(n)=-1+165^2=(165+1)(165-1)$

As $(165^2,165^2-1)=1,$

$(165^2-1)$ will divide $f(n+1)$

$\iff(165^2-1)$ divides $f(n)$

Now establish the base case

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use $k$ as your induction variable you will have to use a different variable your statement.  Assume $165^{2k} - 1= 166m$ and for $2k+2$ the number will change so you'll need a third variable for that.

I suggest that you use subscripts for your $m$ variable.

We will assume $166^{2k} - 1 = 166m_k$ and we need to prove that $165^{2k+2}-1 =166m_{k+1}$ for some integer $m_{k+1}$.

Basic step:   $n=1$ then we want to prove $165^n - 1= 166m_1$ for some $m_1$.

That $165^2 -1 = (165 + 1)(165-1) = 166*164$ so if we let $m_1 = 164$ that is the base case.

Induction step.

Assume $165^{2k} -1 = 166m_k$ for some $m_k$ we want to prove that $165^{2k+2} -1 = 166*m_{k+1}$ for some integer $m_{k+1}$.

Start by noting:

$165^{2k+2}-1=165^{2k}165^2 - 1=$

$165^{2k}*165^2 - 165^2 + 165^2 - 1 =$

$165^2(165^{2k} -1) + (165^2 - 1) = $

$165^2(166m_k) + (166m_1) = $

$166[ 165^2m_k + m_1]$

So if we let $m_{k+1} = 165^2m_k + m_1$ were are done.